# error recorer string con for en r

Tags: string, r, loops

Quiero recorrer una string de texto usando un bucle, pero al ejecutar al código solo me hace la primera iteración.

```
text <- "CTGGTGCTCGTAGACCGCAGAACC";
i=0
i1=i+3
for (i in 1:length(text)){
 DNA <-substr(text,i,i1)
 i=i1+1
 i1=i+2
 print(DNA)
}
```

qual es el error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conseguir la longitud de una variable de tipo texto utiliza `nchar`:

```
for (i in 1:nchar(text))
```

`Length()` se utiliza para vectores, factors y objetos. [Documentación](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/length)

Answer (score -1):

Además, creo que al cambiar el valor de i, ya no le permites que tome todos los valores que tienes dentro del ciclo.
No deberías modificar i, utiliza otra variable diferente para evitar crear el conflicto en ejecución del bucle.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.